# tail recursive slice function of the 99 Problems

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion

The 18th problem of the [99 Problems](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) is as follow:

> Given two indices, `i` and `k`, the slice is the list containing the
>   elements between the `i`'th and `k`'th element of the original list (both
>   limits included). Start counting the elements with 0 (this is the way
>   the `List` module numbers elements).

The `slice` function should behave like:

```
# slice ["a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h";"i";"j"] 2 6;;
- : string list = ["c"; "d"; "e"; "f"; "g"]
```

My version (below) of the slice function is way simpler (in my opinion) than the solution provided on the site.

Can you confirm it is tail recursive ?

<s>Can you explain why the solution provided in 99 Problems is more elegant than the one below ?</s>

```
let slice list i k =   
    let rec sl i k acc = function
        [] -> acc
        |h::t -> if i > 0 then sl (i - 1) (k - 1) acc t else
                 if k > 0 then sl  i (k - 1) (acc@[h]) t else 
                 (acc@[h])   
    in sl i k [] list;;
```

Comment: whether your code is more elegant than the other - for me it is a subjective matter. Personnaly, I find the code of the 99 problems easier to read - but no idea about the elegance ;)

Comment: First of all, [opinion-based questions aren't a good fit for this site and are generally frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252854/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-allow-discussable-questions-or-questions-that-require).

Secondly, what's your measure of elegance? I'd say it depends on the goal. The 99 problems solution breaks the problem down in a very intuitive way, and is easy to understand because it does one thing at a time: first you drop this many, then you take this many. For the purpose of teaching functional programming concepts I'd say it's very elegant.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not a question of elegance but of complexity. This can be implemented in O(n) but your solution is O(n²) which is terrible.

Indeed concatenating two lists with `@` is not a constant time operation. And it's not tail recursive either ([see source code](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/pervasives.mli#L687)). So each concatenation is O(n) and you do O(n) of them so the overall complexity is O(n²).

Comment: OP please accept this answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Note: thanks to `tail_mod_cons`, the `@` operator now is tail-recursive.  [stdlib.ml source](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/stdlib.ml)